# Android Studio: Video View disappears once I set the path to my video (mp4 file)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to embed an mp4 file into the android app but it does not appear on my emulator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
package com.example.videodemo2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.demovideo);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);

        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        videoView.start();

    }
}
```

The video view dissapears once I set the video path. Without the line videoView.SetVideoPath(), the video view is visible (though the mp4 file is not visible).

The mp4 file is in res/raw/

Since it does not show me any error messages, I am struggling with finding the issue.

I checked the file names and its data format, and they seem correct.

I also tried

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.demovideo));
```

but did not work.

Since it does not work even if I copied a file from the internet and ran, it might be some issues regarding the versions of the android studio.

I am using Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 on M1 Mac.

Comment: Have you tried doing something else other than `wrap_content` for the size?

Comment: yes, I have tried multiple sizes (square, match_parent etc.) but none of them worked.